# Export std::Vector Member in a Class

Tags: .net, c++, interop

I want to export a C++ class, which has a member `std::vector<int>`. How to export this class so that my C# application can consume it? And how to write the corresponding .Net code?

This is what I tried so far, following the examples [given here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/168958).

```
 #include <vector>
#  define BOOSTGRAPH_API __declspec(dllexport)
# define EXPIMP_TEMPLATE

EXPIMP_TEMPLATE template class BOOSTGRAPH_API std::vector<int>;

     class BOOSTGRAPH_API MyClass
    {
    public:
        std::vector<int> VectorOfInts;

    public:
        bool operator < (const MyClass  c) const
        {
            return VectorOfInts < c. VectorOfInts;
        }
        bool operator == (const MyClass  c) const
        {
            return VectorOfInts == c. VectorOfInts;
        }
    };
```

But then I'm stucked.

Comment: Is it possible that you forgot to #include <vector>? The compiler seems to not know what vector is.

Comment: @gnobal, no I didn't. Code snippet updated.

Comment: @gnobal, I've fixed the compilation error. But now stuck at don't know how to write the corresponding .Net code. See the updated question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are you trying to do? I see BOOST_GRAPH_API, what are you up to? You will not be able to use native C++ code from .Net directly, neither you should! That would force you to compile all imported dependencies on C++ standard library and boost(!) with clr support...

You need to define interfaces to your classes along with proper factory methods. These can be safely exported and wrapped by C++/CLI objects which you can directly reference within .Net programs:

```
// imyclass.h

__declspec( dllexport ) 
IMyClass* CreateInstance();

__declspec( dllexport ) 
class IMyClass {
public:
    virtual int CompareTo(IMyClass*) = 0;
    virtual ~IMyClass() {}
};

// myclass.h

#include "imyclass.h"
#include <vector>

class MyClass : public IMyClass {
    std::vector<int> mIntVector;
public:
    virtual int CompareTo(IMyClass*);
    // constructors and access functions go here...
};

// myclass.cpp

#include "myclass.h"
#include <memory>

IMyClass* CreateInstance() {
 return new MyClass;
}

// implementations of whatever MyClass should do go here...
```

Observe that only the interface `IMyClass` and its creator is exported by the dll, nothing else. In a C++/CLI project, you define a C++/CLI disposable wrapper which holds a pointer to `IMyClass` and imports only imyclass.h. The wrapper which imprt only `IMyClass` and it's creator should be similar to something shown below, but take care to get the finalizer semantics right, not sure at the moment what is generated autmatically by the compiler...:

```
ref class IMyClassWrapper {
    IMyClass* mPtrResource;

 public:

    int CompareTo(IMyClassWrapper^ pOther) {
        return this->mPtrResource->CompareTo(pOther->mPtrResource);
    }

    IMyClassWrapper() {
     mPtrResource = ::CreateInstance();
    }

    ~IMyClassWrapper() {
     this->!IMyClassWrapper();
    }

 protected:

    !IMyClassWrapper() {
     delete mPtrResource;
     mPtrResource = 0;
    }

};
```

Comment: I would like to pass `std::vector<int>` as return argument to .Net, not sure whether if that's possible

Comment: No it is not. You have to wrap it as shown above. Just be aware of not mixing managed and unmanaged C++ code. You have to create separate projects (one managed, another one unmanaged) and reference you unmanaged dll from the managed project as shown above (or similar, there are some details I might have missed in the post)...

Answer (score 0):

C# can't understand __declspec(dllimport), it can only grok C-style interfaces.  You will have to go through C++/CLI, they offer STL->.NET conversions, IIRC.

Comment: unfortunately a large portion of my C++ code is written in a standard manner ( portable across all platforms) so I am not sure how compile it as CLI helps. It may not even compile!

Comment: @Ngu: If you don't want to compile with a C interface, and you want to interface with .NET code, you have no choice.